# How to setup different permissions on parent/subfolder using FreeBSD/NFS sharing?

Tags: freebsd, nfs

I have the following folder structure:

[image: my folder structure]

Here's my sample/target /etc/exports

```
# cat /etc/exports
/storage -maproot=root -network 192.168.1.0/24
/storage/mysonsvideos -ro -maproot=root -network 192.168.1.0/24
```

I want to be able to:

1. give read/write access to 192.168.1.0/24 if /storage is mapped (which is what I would be doing on my own MacBooks)
2. read-only access to 192.168.1.0/24 if /storage/mysonsvideos is mapped (which is what I would setup on my son's macbook)

But from what I understand, this isn't possible because according to the handbook:
[image]

But maybe you know something I haven't read yet! Thanks a lot